# R merge rows and fill by group in a dataframe

Tags: r

I have a dataframe that I want to merge such that there is only one row per group and the values from other columns are filled in.

```
mydata<-
record_id   instance    off_h   off_c   off_p
1   1   1   NA  NA
1   2   NA  NA  1
1   3   0   0   1
1   4   0   0   1
1   1   0   0   1

Desired_output
record_id   instance    off_h   off_c   off_p
1   1   1   0   1 
1   2   0   0   1
1   3   0   0   1
1   4   0   0   1

mycode:
mydata %>%
group_by(record_id, instance) %>%
fill(off_h, off_c, off_p, .direction = "updown")
```

Comment: `fill` fills in `NA` values. If you have all numerics, maybe you should take the `max` instead? `mydata |> summarise(across(everything(), max), .by = c(record_id, instance))`

Comment: Or perhaps `distinct(my_data)`? It's not clear what you would like to see if any rows have the same record_id (is that the "group" you care about?) but vary in one or more other columns.

Comment: I care about the group!

Comment: Great, what is the group?

Comment: group_by(record_id, instance)

Answer (score 0):

```r
library(dplyr)
mydata %>%
  summarize(
    across(everything(),
           ~ if (any(!is.na(.))) max(., na.rm = TRUE) else 0),
    .by = c(record_id, instance)
  )
#   record_id instance off_h off_c off_p
# 1         1        1     1     0     1
# 2         1        2     0     0     1
# 3         1        3     0     0     1
# 4         1        4     0     0     1
```

For each group (`record_id, instance`), this takes the max of the values present (for each column independently). This means that if you have 2+ rows in a particular group and they both have values in a column, you will silently lose the lesser value(s).